# Java protobuf set fields in the message at root and in the sub-messages

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

How do we build a message instance from a protobuf which has nested messages in java.

Using the proto described below by setting the fields at root and fields in nested messages of the protobuf and return instance of the whole message.

```
message Envelope {

  message quantity {
    optional string a = 1;
    optional string b = 2;
  }
  message quality {
    required string c = 1;
  }

  optional string e = 1;
}
```

In the above message I want to return an instance of Envelope by setting fields at root which is "e" and also setting the fields in nested messages like "a" ,"b" in "quantity" and "c" in "quality". How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

In your protobuf definition, you created 3 message types, two of which nested in the other.

[This nesting is just about the namespace.](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#nested) To actually include the them in `Envelop`, you should write:

```proto
message Envelope {

  message Quantity {
    optional string a = 1;
    optional string b = 2;
  }
  message Quality {
    required string c = 1;
  }

  optional string e = 1;
  optional Quantity quantity = 2;
  optional Quality quality = 3;
}
```